# mono pkg verifying forever on mac

Tags: macos, mono, installation

I'm trying to install the universal Mac installer on OS X 10.11.1 El Capitan. I downloaded from http://www.mono-project.com/download/ and the .pkg file appears fine. When I start it, I get Verifying dialog box (attached screenshot) and it just sits there, no progress along progress bar. Any suggestions appreciated.[Verifying "MonoFramework-MDK-4.2.1.102.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg"...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl4ug.png)

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved"

Comment: I am having the same problem. Haven't had any luck troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found an answer.

1. run /System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app
2. navigate to the installer that is stuck, and install it
3. Profit!

examples and screenshots found at http://osxdaily.com/2016/07/26/fix-stuck-pkg-verifying-installer-mac-os-x/